r difference in each observation within Id
Assuming I have a dataset like this
id   time       cd4  sequence
1   -0.741958   548  1 
1   -0.246407   893  2
1    0.243669   657  3
        
2   -2.7296369  464  1
2   -2.2505131  845  2
2   -0.221766   752  3
2    0.221766   459  4
2    0.77481198 181  5
2    1.256673   434  6

I like to compute the difference in cd4 values , the earliest value with every other value , within that ID.
ID 1, has 3  observations, earliest is at time -0.741, The code should estimate the difference of cd4 values ,
sequence 1 vs sequence 2 : 893 - 548
sequence 1 vs sequence 3 : 657 - 548
sequence 2 vs sequence 4 : 657 - 893

Id 2 has 6 observations, this is 6Choose2, which is 15 different combinations
So expecting a dataset like this
id  time        cd4 seq comb    cd4_lag
1   -0.74195    548 1   1,1     0
1   -0.24640    893 2   1,2     345
1   0.243669    657 3   1,3     109
1                       2,3    -236
2   -2.72963    464 1   1,1 
2   -2.25051    845 2   1,2     381
2   -0.22176    752 3   1,3     288
2   0.221766    459 4   1,4     -5
2   0.774811    181 5   1,5     -283
2   1.256673    434 6   1,6     -30
                        2,3     -93
                        2,4     -386
                        2,5     -664
                        2,6     -411
                        3,4     -293
                        3,5     -571
                        3,6     -318
                        4,5     -278
                        4,6     -25
                        5,6      253

Thanks for any suggestions , advise.

Is it intentional that each sequence includes 1,1 but not any other self-matches like 2,2?

Probably to keep the times for all observations in the output and not have duplicates.

@JonSpring, Edward is correct, sequence including 1,1, 2,2  is irrelevant.

Maybe something like this? I have left out the 1,1 self matches since it wasn't clear to me why those should be included but no other self matches.
library(dplyr)
df |>
  inner_join(df |> select(-time),
            join_by(id, sequence < sequence)) |>
  mutate(cd4_lag = cd4.y - cd4.x)

Result
   id      time cd4.x sequence.x cd4.y sequence.y cd4_lag
1   1 -0.741958   548          1   893          2     345
2   1 -0.741958   548          1   657          3     109
3   1 -0.246407   893          2   657          3    -236
4   2 -2.729637   464          1   845          2     381
5   2 -2.729637   464          1   752          3     288
6   2 -2.729637   464          1   459          4      -5
7   2 -2.729637   464          1   181          5    -283
8   2 -2.729637   464          1   434          6     -30
9   2 -2.250513   845          2   752          3     -93
10  2 -2.250513   845          2   459          4    -386
11  2 -2.250513   845          2   181          5    -664
12  2 -2.250513   845          2   434          6    -411
13  2 -0.221766   752          3   459          4    -293
14  2 -0.221766   752          3   181          5    -571
15  2 -0.221766   752          3   434          6    -318
16  2  0.221766   459          4   181          5    -278
17  2  0.221766   459          4   434          6     -25
18  2  0.774812   181          5   434          6     253


you dont write code, you write poetry in R, your solution worked perfect. Thank you.

library(dplyr)

inner_join(df, df, by="id", relationship = "many-to-many") |> 
    filter(sequence.x<sequence.y & sequence.x!=1 | sequence.x==1) |>
    transmute(id=id, time=time.y, cd4=cd4.y, seq=sequence.y, 
              comb=paste(sequence.x, sequence.y, sep=","), 
              cd4_lag=cd4.y-cd4.x)


      id   time   cd4   seq comb  cd4_lag
 1     1 -0.742   548     1 1,1         0
 2     1 -0.246   893     2 1,2       345
 3     1  0.244   657     3 1,3       109
 4     1  0.244   657     3 2,3      -236
 5     2 -2.73    464     1 1,1         0
 6     2 -2.25    845     2 1,2       381
 7     2 -0.222   752     3 1,3       288
 8     2  0.222   459     4 1,4        -5
 9     2  0.775   181     5 1,5      -283
10     2  1.26    434     6 1,6       -30
11     2 -0.222   752     3 2,3       -93
12     2  0.222   459     4 2,4      -386
13     2  0.775   181     5 2,5      -664
14     2  1.26    434     6 2,6      -411
15     2  0.222   459     4 3,4      -293
16     2  0.775   181     5 3,5      -571
17     2  1.26    434     6 3,6      -318
18     2  0.775   181     5 4,5      -278
19     2  1.26    434     6 4,6       -25
20     2  1.26    434     6 5,6       253

